# How to change the gridview width and rename the header after binding data

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

i try to change the gridview size and rename the header after binding the data,but i got the error "Index was out of range" because my data are more than 100px,How to solve it?

```
                conn.Open();
                cmdString = "SQL";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@courseID", CourseID);
                dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                gvAssignment.DataSource = dtr;
                gvAssignment.Columns[7].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
                gvAssignment.DataBind();                  
                dtr.Close();
                conn.Close();
```

another method no error but the size not change to 100

```
    protected void gvAssignment_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[7].Width = 100;
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem isn't because of the Width Size... That situation never throw an Exception... Are you Sure that you have 8 Columns?

Comment: Did you set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`? Just answer Yes or No

Comment: no,i did't set AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the DataBind first, like follows:

```
   gvAssignment.DataBind();  
   gvAssignment.Columns[7].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
```

You can also try updating the column width after the data has been bound. To ensure this, we can set it inside the gridview bound event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvAssignment.DataBound += new EventHandler(gvAssignment_DataBound);
}

void gvAssignment_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    gvAssignment.Columns[7].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100); 
}
```

Comment: "Select" "Download" "LearnerID" "CourseID" "Name" "UploadDate" "Mark" "Comment" This is my column,and i want to change the "Comment" width

Comment: @user1848681 see my edit. I believe you will need to bind the data first, before changing the column width. W/out the bind, the columns do not yet exist.

Comment: @user1848681 do a simple print on gvAssignment.Row(0).Cells.Count after the conn.close() to see how many there are.. (sanity check)

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting

Comment: sorry, change Row(0) to Rows[0]

Comment: '<asp:GridView ID="gvAssignment" runat="server" onrowcommand="gvAssignment_RowCommand" OnDataBound="Gridview1_DataBound">'

 'ASP.online_assessment_downloadassignment_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Gridview1_DataBound'

Comment: private void Gridview1_DataBound(EventArgs e)
        {
            gvAssignment.Columns[7].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        }

Comment: @user1848681 sorry, you need to update the event signature. see update

Comment: can help me check the another method got what problem,because 2nd method no problem but the output no match 100px

Comment: @user1848681 see update, this time, the event hook up is done in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query. "Index was out of range" may point on the column index (if you don't have 8 columns on your query)

Comment: "Select" "Download" "LearnerID" "CourseID" "Name" "UploadDate" "Mark" "Comment" This is my column,and i want to change the "Comment" width