# gridview table set width after bind data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

i use "GridView" to bind the data when user select from dropdownlist,the problem of me is the "Comment" column is  out of the table range when user input too much word in the "Comment",can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: I haven't done this but in asp.net forums, its written that we can manually control the width of column in gridview using GridView1.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(10);  or another method is column.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772529/how-to-change-the-gridview-width-and-rename-the-header-after-binding-data

i done this in previous but not work,error is "Index was out of range"

Comment: there are no tables in your data set so migh be its giving index out of range exception

Comment: how to do it after databind()?

Comment: Use the `RowDatabound` event; Or, if you are not concerned about IE<9 or Safari<3.2 , use css style: `tr td:last-child{max-width:100px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a css class to wrap word after fix length.

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .DisplayDesc { width:250px;word-break : break-all }

 </style>
```

apply this class in gridview

```
   <asp:Label CssClass="DisplayDesc" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TransText") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Not tested but may be this can help you.